# Has anyone tried to make a JHipster blueprint without Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jhipster, jooq

Can it be done?
Any advice is welcomed, thinking of replacing it with jOOQ.

Comment: You might want to checkout https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-jooq

Comment: Good suggestion from Matt, you should contact Marcelo Shima who wrote this one, he might have good insights to share.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Which sub-generators should I override in order to get rid of Hibernate?